# Not sure how to check if a functional dependency is in F+

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies

I am having trouble with a database design problem having to do with functional dependencies.

Here is the relation schema R along with its set of functional dependencies F:

```
R = (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
F = {A->BC, CD->AB, EF->AD, B->AEF}
```

My goal is to verify whether DE->AC can be derived from F, namely, if it's in F+ (the F closure).

I understand the Armstrong axioms (the algebra-like operations one can do on functional dependencies to manipulate them into a true statement for R and F) of reflexivity, augmentation, transitivity, union, decomposition, and psuedotransitivity, but I am not sure I am applying them in the right way to get a yes or no answer as to whether DE->AC is included in F+.

I got this:

```
Given: A->BC
Given: CD->AB
    Therefore: CD->A and CD->B
From there I deduced that CD->BC by the transitivity rule.
I then cancelled out the C's on both sides:
    D->B
After that I augmented E's on both sides:
    DE->BE
By decomposition, I now have:
    DE->B and DE->E, of which DE->B will be what I want to work with to try to make the right-hand side AC.
```

I now have the appropriate left-hand side to this functional dependency but I don't know what to do next to make the right-hand side equivalent to AC.

What comes next?

Answer (score 1):

Proceed with DE->BE and B->AEF to obtain DE->ABDEF.

Now proceed with A->BC etc etc until you have an attribute set on the RHS that is a superset of AC.